# In terms of performance, is it faster to move a rect or make a new rect in Pygame?

Tags: python, performance, pygame, rect

Which code in a class would be run faster?

```
def update():
    self.rect=pygame.Rect(self.x,self.y,50,50)
```

or

```
def update():
    self.rect.x=self.x
    self.rect.y=self.y
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is, **moving a rectangle is faster.**

The long answer is, **it depends.** As with many performance questions, it's really hard to know how much faster things will be in terms of CPU cycles or memory footprint.

Moving a rectangle is faster *in most cases* because when you reference `self.rect.x` and `self.rect.y` you are actually referencing pointers to memory where these values are stored. Changing these values in memory can be very inexpensive and quick. Also, when you create `new Rect` you must allocate a new block of memory to that object, which can take time.

On the other hand, Pygame may re-render the new location of your rectangle on the screen, which **could be cheaper** than just creating a new object. If you wanted the old rectangle to disappear, you may need to edit a part of that object to make it now invisible.

**Overall,** something being *fast* or *cheap* can depend on the context, language, operating system, hardware, or a number of different factors in the environment of the running code. Keep this in mind. Another confounding factor is the fact that Python is a [compiled language](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201803/is_python_interpreted_or_compiled_yes.html).